# mockery not able to register substitute

Tags: unit-testing, mockery

I have a problem registering substitutes with mockery.
My usecase is that I want to substitute `react-native-router-flux` with my own. So I created a file `rn-router-mock.js` which resides in a path something `like ./../test/mock/rn-router-mock` relative to my test file.

My code `mockery.registerSubstitute('react-native-router-flux', './../test/mock/rn-router-mock')` fails with an error

```
Error: Cannot find module './../../test/mock/rn-router-mock'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Module._load (module.js:276:25)
```

However note that I am able to `require('./../test/mock/rn-router-mock')` from the same test code.

And the same works when I give the full path to the mock module.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery/issues/22

Ok, the path has to be relative to the file that requires it.